# get both output parameter and ResultSet values from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to get the output parameter for passing into another SP so I created a test too see if I could get the string from it but an exception gets thrown:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed

Without the `cs.getMoreResults();` another exception is thrown:

> java.sql.SQLException: Output parameters have not yet been processed. Call getMoreResults().

If I do remove my  `if (rs.next()) {` then it works.
How do I get the output parameter and still use my `if rs.next`?

```
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (userid.trim().equals("Developer")|| password.trim().equals("Dev!n_234"))
            isSuccess2=true;
        z = getString(R.string.login_succes);
        if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
            z = getString(R.string.indsæt_rigtigt_bruger);
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl) + "L1)";

                } else {
                    String ID;
                    ID = setingPreferences.getString("companyid", "");
                    CallableStatement cs = null;
                    String query = "{ call [system].[usp_validateUserLogin](?,?,?,?,?)}  ";
                    cs = con.prepareCall(query);
                    cs.setString(1, userid);
                    cs.setString(2, password);
                    cs.setString(3, ID);
                    cs.setBoolean(4, true);
                    cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
                    ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();

                    cs.getMoreResults();
                    System.out.println("Test : " + cs.getString(5));

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        z = getString(R.string.login_succes);
                        isSuccess = true;

                    } else {
                        z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = getString(R.string.Exceptions)+"L2)";
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", ex);
            }
        }
        return z;

    }
}
```

Comment: Read the [javadoc for `Statement#getMoreResults`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--) : "and implicitly closes any current ResultSet"

Comment: Try calling `cs.execute()` (instead of `cs.executeQuery()`) and then see if you can get the output parameter value from `cs.getString(5)`.

Comment: i can't use `cs.execute` as it is incompatible type with my `ResultSet rs =`
but if i do remove my `if (rs.next()) {` then it works how exactly can i use both things in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to process the ResultSet value(s) first, and then retrieve the output parameter value. That's because SQL Server sends the output parameter values *after* sending the result sets (ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684906/2144390)).

So, this won't work:

```java
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
System.out.println(cs.getString(5));  // clobbers the ResultSet
rs.next();  // error
```

but this should be okay:

```java
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // do stuff
}
System.out.println(cs.getString(5));  // retrieve the output parameter value
```

Comment: arh okay so that was the cause of it cause i was trying to get it before it was there